# How to change Android notification bar drawer running apps background color?

Tags: android, notifications

I need to know how do i change the running apps notification drawer background color?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming question. You did not show any research effort at all. Anyways to answer your question:

*Notification drawer can't be changed in any way (including background) unless rooted and you install a custom theme.*

Hope that helps.